# Proof that the infimum of a given set $E$ is unique

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Prove that a lower bound of a set might not be unique but the infimum of a given set is unique.

Attempt: Consider some $E \subset \mathbb{R} $ such that $E \neq \emptyset$.  $E$ is bounded below $\iff \exists  m \in \mathbb{R}\,\, \text{such that}\,\, a  \geq m\,\, \forall a \in E $.

Presumably the only case where  a lower bound need be unique is if the end interval of the set is infinity i.e some subset of the form $(-\infty, p)$, where $p \in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove the uniqueness of infimum: Suppose there exists two such infimum $t_1, t_2 \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $t_1 \leq a $ and $ t_2 \leq a\,\forall a \in E$.  So $t_1$ and $t_2$ are both lower bounds for the set $E$ and in particular, since $t_1$ and $t_2$ are both infimum, $t_1 \leq t_2$ and $t_2 \leq t_1$ by the definition of infimum.  Hence by the Trichotomy Principle, we conclude $t_1 = t_2$.

Is this okay? If so,  am I correct in what I said above that provided the subset does not extend to $-\infty$, lower bounds for the set need not be unique?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is ok. The remark preceding it is not. A set of the form $(-\infty , p)$ is simply not bounded below. In general, if a set $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ is bounded below that it has infinitely many lower bounds, but only one greatest lower bound.

Note: the plural of infimum is infima.

Comment: Okay thanks.  But why does the question say 'the lower bound of a set might not be unique'  This implies to me there exists a set which has only one lower bound.

Comment: that is not carefully worded indeed. Any bounded below subset of the reals has infinitely many lower bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that M, M ′ are suprema of A. Then M ≤ M ′ since M ′ is an upper bound of A and M is a least upper bound; similarly, M ′ ≤ M, so M = M ′. If m, m′ are inﬁma of A, then m ≥ m′ since m′ is a lower bound of A and m is a greatest lower bound; similarly, m′ ≥ m, so m = m′.
If inf A and sup A exist, then A is nonempty. Choose x ∈ A, Then inf A ≤ x ≤ sup A
since inf A is a lower bound of A and sup A is an upper bound. It follows that inf A ≤ sup A.

Comment: This doesn't really address the OP's question, who wanted advice on the proof given in the post.